# MSSQLSERVER 2008 R2 Hanging After set Index for tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am seeing some really odd problems in SQL Server 2008 R2

There is table that has approximately 2000 new records inserted daily.
We need to search on a `nvarchar` column and I set a non-clustered index for this table.

And it works fine we only have a problem when need to take some yearly reports we get the report very fast (the report that takes 5 min now it loaded in 10 Sec). After we get the report, SQL Server Hangs!

By restarting the service it is still Hanging, so we need to restart the server. Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked the SQL error logs and system event logs?

Comment: not yet i don't have access to server, Saturday  i have to go and check it